# How to use regular expression to replace non-digits and math operators together?

Tags: java, regex, string

How do I only keep chars of `[0-9]` and `[+-*/]` in a string in Java?  My approach is to use a union to create a single character class comprised of `[0-9]` and `[+-*/]` character classes, but I got an empty string.

Here is an example string I use: 10+2*2-5

```
public void cleanup(String s){
    String regex = "[^0-9[^+-*//]]";
    String tmp = s.replaceAll(regex, "");
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you [edit] your question to include some example inputs and what output you expect.  That second `^` looks suspicious, though, as does the `-` in the inner range. Why do you have nested ranges anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want you character class (`[...]`) to include the range `0-9` and the additional characters `*`, `/`, `-` and `+`. All you need is to put them one after the other and escape `-` (`\\-`), unless it's the last character. Then, use a negation construct (`^`) inside at the beginning:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "a3f6+[,b7*\"d/-8u";
        System.out.println(test.replaceAll("[^0-9/*+-]", ""));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
36+7*/-8
```

Comment: except you cannot just put in - and expect regex to treat it as a dash, your regex would strip all - characters in the test string, if you had any.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue there with the way you have use `-` in the second part, if you use `-` in the middle of an expression like you have in `[^+-*/]` it thinks that is part of a range expression like you did with `0-9` so you need to put the `-` at the end of the expression so that it isn't treated as a range.

The following expression should do what you are after:

```
[^0-9*/+-]
```

Comment: Why do you need `/` 2 times?

Comment: It was in the original regex and I accidentally left it in when I did mine, no actual reasoning. Also it shouldn't actually effect the result.

Answer (score 0):

What about `s/[^0-9]|[^+-*//]//g` for the regex?